# upload image using ResponseBody in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httprequest

i am using this code for upload image but i all time get 415 Unsupported Media Type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateImage" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseMsg uploadFileHandler( 
            @RequestHeader(value="userid" ,required=false) String userid,
            @RequestHeader(value="name" ,required=false) String name,
            @RequestHeader(value="phone" ,required=false) Integer phone,
            @RequestBody MultipartFile multipartFile, 
            HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        System.out.println("hi");
        String orgName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            orgName = CommonUtils.createUniqueFileName(orgName);

            ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
            String filePath = "uploadedImages/" + orgName;
            String completePath = sc.getRealPath("/") + "/" + filePath;
            File dest = new File(completePath);
            multipartFile.transferTo(dest);

            ResponseMsg responseMsg = CommonUtils.checkParam(userid, name, phone,filePath);
            if (responseMsg.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
                responseMsg = userService.updateProfile(userid, name, phone,filePath);
            return responseMsg;
    }
```

Comment: can you paste the html form code here?

Comment: make sure you put `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` on the form tag's attribute list.

Comment: please chk its olready post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in  servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

In controller

public void method(@RequestParam MultipartFile file){.. }

Answer (score 1):

- Have you got a [MultipartResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html) in you application context, eg: [CommonsMultipartResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html)?
- Do you have a [HttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) to convert HTTP request body into MultipartFile? By default Spring doesn't come with this. Read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody
- It seems to me rather than mapping the whole HTTP request (eg: `@RequestBody MultipartFile multipartFile`), it's better to map the particular form field only, eg: `@RequestParam('someFileUpload') MultipartFile uploadedFile`, this is assuming you use a file select in your html form eg: `<input type="file" name="someFileUpload"/>`